# Apex - Invalid return type Map<String, EmbeddedClass>

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a Salesforce Apex class that's enhancing the functionality of a custom button. I want to provide back key/value pairs with information for the front-end.

What I'm struggling with is being able to get this new class to save. The error I'm receiving is:

**`Invalid return type: Map<String,ButtonCaseHandler.ResponseWrapper> at line 37 column 51`**

I've checked that all of the values I'm passing into the ResponseWrapper.value is a list of strings. At this point I'm not too sure where to go with this.

```
global class ButtonCaseHandler {

private static final String defaultNewCaseRecordType = 'ID1';

private static List<String> getGhsOpenCases(String memberId, String dependentId){
    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    try{
        //1. check all GHS open cases for this member within the last 14 days
        List<Case> openCases = [
            SELECT Id, casenumber,super_diagnosis__c, CreatedDate
              FROM Case
             WHERE recordTypeId IN ('ID1','ID2')
               AND createdDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:14
               AND status = 'Open'
               AND Account.member_id__c = :memberId
               AND (Account.dependent_id__c = :dependentId OR Account.dependent_id__c = null)
          ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
        ];

        for(Case c : openCases){
            result.add('Case, '+c.casenumber+', has a super diagnosis of '+ c.super_diagnosis__c + 'and was created on '+ c.createdDate.format('dd-MMM-yyyy'));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }

    return result;
}

webService static Map<String,ResponseWrapper> AccountCreateCase(Id aId){
    Map<String, ResponseWrapper> result = new Map<String,ResponseWrapper>();
    try{
        Account currentAccount = [
                                    SELECT Id, Viewing_User_Profile_Name__c, member_id__c, 
                                           Policy__c, Name, dependent_id__c
                                      FROM Account 
                                     WHERE Id = :aId
                                     LIMIT 1
                                ];        

        //create the mapping between profile names and case record types
        Map<String,String> profileNameToReRecordTypeId = new Map<String,String>();
        profileNameToReRecordTypeId.put('RCNAME1','ID1');                                
        profileNameToReRecordTypeId.put('RCNAME2','ID2');
        profileNameToReRecordTypeId.put('System Administrator','ID1');

        String caseRecordType = profileNameToReRecordTypeId.get(currentAccount.Viewing_User_Profile_Name__c);

        if(String.isBlank(caseRecordType)){
            caseRecordType = defaultNewCaseRecordType;
        }

        ///validation if it's a GHS profile
        if(currentAccount.Viewing_User_Profile_Name__c == 'RCNAME1'){
            List<String> ghsOpenCasesString = ButtonCaseHandler.getGhsOpenCases(currentAccount.member_id__c,currentAccount.dependent_id__c);

            if(!ghsOpenCasesString.isEmpty()){
                ResponseWrapper oc = new ResponseWrapper();
                oc.value = ghsOpenCasesString;
                result.put('openCases',oc);
                ResponseWrapper ic = new ResponseWrapper();
                ic.value = new List<String>{'true'};                    
                result.put('invokeConfirm',ic);
            }
        }

        //create the URL hack for the time being. 
        ///we will want to update this later on to create the case and relocate to the newly created case
        String relocateUrl = '/500/e?RecordType=URLTORELOCATETHEUSERTO';

        ResponseWrapper ru = new ResponseWrapper();
        ru.value = new List<String>{relocateUrl}; 
        result.put('relocateUrl',ru);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Error in AccountCreateCase method: ' + e);
        //instantiate the error long class
        ErrorLog errorLog = new ErrorLog();               
        ErrorLog__c methodErr = new ErrorLog__c(
            method_name__c = 'AccountCreateCase',
            method_source__c = 'ButtonCaseHandler',
            stack_trace__c = e.getMessage(),
            application_data__c = '{"accountId": '+aId+'}'
        );
        errorLog.logError(methodErr, true, '');   
    }

    return result;
}

global class ResponseWrapper {
    webService List<String> value {get; set;}
}
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to a lack of support for Maps as a return type when the method is a web service. SOAP doesn't support map, so you need to convert to a list of lists, where you have a list of keys and then a list of values.

Comment: Why is this even a WebService?  You can create a custom button that launches a Visualforce Page that runs your logic instead.